# Why can't I access the pouch?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

For some reason I cannot access my pouch. I'm about half way through the game, and for some reason the <kbd>-</kbd> button will not respond while I'm in game play. It's not the button/controller, the <kbd>-</kbd> works off screen when checking my gear. My son was viewing the pouch just before he noticed he could no longer use it. Did he disable something or is it a glitch? I can't use the shield or potions!

Comment: There's a point late in the game where you lose all your gear and have to collect it again. Are you sure you aren't in that spot? Do you see bobokin heads while holding the - button>

Comment: @JohnoBoy: If that were the case, he'd still be able to view the pouch but he's suggesting he can't even view it.  (at least, that's what it sounds like)  Perhaps he has the cursed medal equipped?

Comment: Could be. I never used that so I can't really tell the effect. You can only remove it at the item check, no?

Comment: Why the down vote? This is a situation most players will find themselves in during the game. I did.

Comment: @splatteredbits: Look at the [original revision](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/51738/1) and you'll probably see why.

Comment: @JeffMercado That makes more sense.  Thanks to JohnoBoy for the edit!

Answer (score 15):

**This happens if the Cursed Medal is in your adventure pouch.**  When in your pouch, the Cursed Medal increases the frequency of hearts and rupees, but it doesn't allow you to open, or equip items from, your adventure pouch.

The Cursed Medal gets in your pouch unexpectedly if you have an empty spot in your pouch when you receive the Medal from Batreaux.  I had this happen to me.

To get it out of your pouch, **you'll need to drop it at the item check,** which is in the Skyloft Bazaar.

Comment: yup , thats it. I was unawre that my son acquired the cursed medal. He put in2 storage and that solved the problem. THANKS

Comment: @pumzilla: if this answer covers your question, you should mark it as the chosen answer.